# Hosted Blazor WASM GetFromJsonAsync: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor-webassembly

I have tried digging and debugging but can't seem to figure out why Http.Json.GetFromJsonAsync isn't able to convert. The error that I get back is as follows (abridged)

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Onero.Shared.StudentDTO]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.
System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Onero.Shared.StudentDTO].
```

Here is my code:

```
// In the blazor wasm client
    
public async Task<IEnumerable<StudentDTO>> GetStudentsAsync()
{
    return await http.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<StudentDTO>>("api/Students");
}

// My controller
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<StudentDTO>>> GetStudents()
{
    return await _context.Students
        .Select(x => StudentToDTO(x))
        .ToListAsync();
}

// My classes
public class StudentDTO
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ExamScores> Results { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Guardian> Guardians { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ExamScores> Results { get; set; }
}

public class ExamScores
{
    public long ID{ get; set; }
    public long StudentId { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public Exam ExamType { get; set; }   
    public double Score { get; set; }
}

// Startup.cs ConfigureServices
services.AddDbContext<ResultsContext>(opt =>
                                             opt.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("FirstPrototype")));

services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddJsonOptions(
                    x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve
                );

// Context
public class ResultsContext : DbContext
{
    public ResultsContext(DbContextOptions<ResultsContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<ExamScores> ResultsList { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Guardian> Guardians { get; set; }
}
```

When I try logging the controller method, what I get back from _context is in fact

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Onero.Shared.StudentDTO]
```

I am not sure if this is a problem with how I set up my database and migrations? Perhaps it has to do with the `JsonSerializerOptions`in my `ConfigureServices`? But if it did, then why is my controller method reporting that I'm getting back a list of my object, yet my client can't deserialize it? I'd appreciate help/advice. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact yes, it did have to do with the `JsonSerializerOptions`. I had to do the following to my `GetStudentsAsync` method in the client:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<StudentDTO>> GetStudentsAsync()
{
    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
    {
        ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve,
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
    };
    return await http.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<StudentDTO>>("api/Students", options);
}
```

I gleaned that from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.referencehandler.preserve?view=net-5.0#system-text-json-serialization-referencehandler-preserve) and then it occurred to me that perhaps property names didn't match because of casing which is why I then set `PropertyNameCaseInsensitive` to true.

Comment: And what happens with just the ReferenceHandler.Preserve, ie without PropertyNameCaseInsensitive?    Because the property naming rarely is a problem.

Comment: Without ```PropertyNameCaseInsensitive``` I no longer got back an error but the properties were null, i.e, I did a foreach student in StudentDTOs and ```student.Name``` would be ```null```, ```student.ID``` would be ```0```, etc